# Why didn't Lu Xiaojun get to lift 177kg at the 2012 London Olympic Games?

Tags: rules, olympics, weightlifting

See video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1vyuSmxTpo&t=34m15s).

---

Why didn't the jury overturn the decision for Lu Xiaojun's attempt at 177kg at the [2012 London Olympic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weightlifting_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_77_kg) when he missed the minute countdown due to a "tactical hiccup"?

> "...there's been some kind of strange clerical error there because
>   they started the clock and Lu Xiaojun ... oh this is very very
>   confusing because Lu Xiaojun's clock started too early there..." -
>   commentator #1

> "...when you follow yourself in weightlifting you have two minutes on
>   the clock. He was only given one minute on the clock there because the
>   other lifter hasn't come out..." - commentator #2

So, Lu Xiaojun wasn't following himself (technically), so he doesn't get two minutes, but was that really an oversight on their part? Just seems like a withdrawal from Lu Haojie should have been more apparent to the coach/everyone. Did Lu Xiaojun's coach think that the timer that was running was for Lu Haojie who silently posted no figure? Right after Lu Haojie's failed attempt at 175kg Lu Xiaojun successfully snatches 175kg, so that'd be 1 minute on the timer after Lu Xiaojun for Lu Haojie (who didn't see the stage), then Lu Xiaojun's 1 minute timer would have started immediately after. How did the coach/anyone not notice that the timer cycled twice first on behalf of Lu Haojie and then reset for Lu Xiaojun? Is this because in the one minute you're allotted you can either post or not post a figure, and that these postings are not immediately apparent? It stands to reason that a "no post" should have been made apparent. Why didn't Lu Xiaojun follow himself? What decides the order of lifts? Seriously, isn't this weird? The klaxon sounded on the second cycle for Lu Xiaojun's attempt at 177kg. Why didn't the klaxon sound at the end of Lu Haojie's 1 minute "no post"?